# Confusion about the relation between Einstein $A$ and $B$ coefficients

Tags: quantum-mechanics, frequency, physical-constants

In hyperphysics website [it's shown](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/optmod/eincoef.html)
$$\frac{A}{B} = 8πh\frac{\nu^3}{c^3}.$$

But in many famous textbook like Quantum Mechanics: Concepts and Applications Textbook by Nouredine Zettili the formula is written down
$$\frac{A}{B} = 8πħ\frac{ν^3}{c^3}.$$

And more surprisingly I got 2 different Questions where I had applied this 2 different formulas to have the correct answers.

Comment: Is the difference between the equations the fact that one has $h$ and the other $\hbar$?

Comment: Which page in Zettili? Which eq.?

Comment: sorry , I have seen it in quantum mechanics and its application 5th edition by Ajoy ghatak Loknathan. equation no 10.